# getter not getting values for new record on validation rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getter-setter

I have a form_for for creating a new record. I have set getter and setter methods to access form field in my view. Below are my getter ans setter methods with my form view,

Getter & Setter Methods respectively :

```
def manufacturer_model_name
  self.manufacturer_models.pluck(:name).join(', ') unless  self.manufacturer_models.blank?      
end

def manufacturer_model_name=(names)
  names = names.split(',').map{|n| n.strip}.delete_if(&:empty?) if names.present?
  names.uniq.each do |name|
    id = ManufacturerModel.where(:name => name, :manufacturer_id => manufacturer.id).first_or_create.id         
    if self.new_record?
      self.user_skill_manufacturer_models.build(:user_skill_id => self.id, :manufacturer_model_id => id)
    else
      self.user_skill_manufacturer_models.where(:user_skill_id => self.id, :manufacturer_model_id => id).first_or_create.id 
    end 
  end if names.present?
end
```

Form View:

```
= f.text_field :manufacturer_model_name, :class => 'form-control
```

My problem is that, my input field is autocomplete with multiple set to true, to get multiple values. when user enters multiple comma separated values and submits form and if there are any errors on the form, my new action is rendered and user losts all the entered values forcing him to reenter all again. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to make a `manufacturer_model_name_form` field or some such via `attr_accessor`, and then parse that in `validate`. It would look something like this:

```
class ManufacturerModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :manufacturer_model_name_form

  validate :validate_manufacturer_model_name

  def validate_manufacturer_model_name
    errors.add(:manufacturer_model_name, 'not a valid manufacturer model name') if !!true # perform your validation here in place of `!!true`
  end
end
```

Then, in your form, you would use `manufacturer_model_name_form` instead of `manufacturer_model_name`:

```
= f.text_field :manufacturer_model_name_form, :class => 'form-control'
```